# What is wrong in this Polygon in MYSQL 5.7.19?

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3, geospatial, polygons, mysql-5.7

So, I am trying to save a POLYGON in MYSQL using Geospatial functions... I found several examples online like the following:

```
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((
13.517837674890684 76.453857421875,
13.838079936422464 77.750244140625,
14.517837674890684 79.453857421875,
13.517837674890684 76.453857421875,
13.517837674890684 76.453857421875
))');

SELECT  ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((
-98.07697478272888 30.123832577126326,
-98.07697478272888 30.535734310413392,
-97.48302581787107 30.535734310413392,
-97.48302581787107 30.123832577126326,
-98.07697478272888 30.123832577126326
))')
```

The problem is when I tried to make my own, it returns the following error:
Error Code: 3037. Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext.

This is the code I used...

```
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('Polygon((
-99.16939973831177 19.42468828496807,
-99.16710376739502 19.424607339789876,
-99.16712522506714 19.422907481732416,
-99.168541431427 19.421996836172347,
-99.16989326477051 19.422947954749972
))');
```

These are all longitude-latitude pairs, I think it has to do something with the order but the current order is already consecutive.

Can somebody give me a hint, please?

Thank you

EDIT: As they mention in the comments section, by definition a Polygon must be closed.

I am using Google Maps Javascript API v3 to draw a Polygon and then using the "overlaycomplete" event listener which fires a function when the Polygon closes. The function that fires basically print the coordinates given by the API.

If a Polygon must close exactly, why is the API not giving the exact coordinates? Is there a work around?

Comment: A polygon is by definition closed. So the first and last point have to be the same.

Comment: Thank you @Solarflare, somehow I forgot about it thinking Google Maps Javascript API would give me the right format for the Polygon. As I said, I am taking the Polygon coordinates from Google Maps API, listening to the "overlaycomplete" event, which is supposed to fire when the Polygon is closed. Do you have any idea why the API is not giving the exact closed polygon coordinates? Thank you

Comment: If you need the polygon closed, add an additional point to the end of its path (equal to the first point).  The google maps API will "auto close" paths for polygons, so doesn't have that restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the polygon should be close  this way

```
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('Polygon((
-99.16939973831177 19.42468828496807,
-99.16710376739502 19.424607339789876,
-99.16712522506714 19.422907481732416,
-99.168541431427 19.421996836172347,
-99.16989326477051 19.422947954749972, 
-99.16939973831177 19.42468828496807
))');
```

Comment: Actually, the two first "SELECT" queries I mentioned are executing just fine. The problem is with the last one I mention. Thank you